# iPhone App Identifier issue

Tags: iphone, xcode

I switched from a wildcard identifier to a fixed one, but since then it does not work anymore. I made sure that it is the same in the info.plist, but when I try to select it in the build settings it says that the application identifier does not match (in grey, deselected).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not posting code, that's what you're doing wrong. :-)

Comment: @CanSpice: With this issue there's no code to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three places where the bundle ID is listed: info.pist, dist.plist (the entitlements file), and the provisioning profile. Make sure all three match. Restart Xcode while you're at it, sometimes Xcode does not notice profile changes without a restart.